# Fill out a form with PHP object via JavaScript ( JSON )

Tags: javascript, object

I managed to fill out a form whith a user ID  in javascript doing:

( In php file)

```
<..button onclick="fillOut(UserId)"......
```

( In javascript file )

```
fillOut(UserId){

        form = document.formulario;
        form.valor3.value = UserId;

}
```

Ok, that works but now i would need to pass an object to the form

I have an object in php

```
User U = new User();

<button onclick="fillOut(U)"...... 

( In javascript file )
fillOut(U){
        form = document.formulario;
        form.valor3.value = U;
}
```

Unfortunately that not works, the javascript do not accept the object.
I am not sure if it is possible to do it. I think that I have to use JSON to do so, 
but i do not have idea how to do it.

Some clues?? any idea??

Thank you very much!

Comment: What has this to do with PHP?? Any idea?? Some clues?? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing server and client side languages.

You shouldn't try to pass it directly to JavaScript, instead, send a Ajax call to the server, which will return appropriate response in string (or JSON) form, which in turn is caught by the JavaScript, and fill in the form.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I am new in ajax, I will try to start from the begining, and try som basic funtionality.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the PHP object directly in the Javascript code which is not possible.

Instead render the php object as a Javascript object using json_encode inside a script tag (make it available at the client side).

Try this:

```
<?php
    User U = new User();
?>

<button onclick="fillOut()"..
<script type="text/javascript">
    var user = <?php echo  json_encode(U);?>;
    fillOut(U){
        U = U || user;
        form = document.formulario;
        form.valor3.value = U;
    }

</script>
```

Comment: OK, I will try it, but wich is the best option use AJAX (as truth says) or json_encode ??

Comment: @nasy: I generally try to avoid generating JavaScript with PHP. This method works too, I just think it's cleaner to have that separation between server-side and client-side code.

Comment: @Truth Agreed. However it depends when to you either of the approach. I would use the json_encode in the page itself if all we need is some simple attribtues at client side and avoid AJAX for that.